# AlarmManager "Expired Alarm" "result:4 android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have published App, that work with AlarmManagerm, To Active in a exact time, The Application was working well, But suddenly it stop working, When I Check the log of the device I notice that at the Time that I set to the alarm the Device say: V/AlarmManager: "Expired Alarm" "result:4 OR 12 Or 8
here is my code that dtop working without any change!

```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            Log.d("--V--", "----Alarm set----");

        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT  && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            Log.d("--V--", "----Alarm setExact----");

        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo acInf0 = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                alarmManager.setAlarmClock(acInf0, pendingIntent);
            Log.d("--V--", "----Alarm setAlarmClock----");

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("--V--", "NOT SET " + ex);
    }
    Log.d("--V--", "Time In Calendar::: " + LocalTime.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) + "date: "+Localdate.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was?